# referencing my facebook application with a querystring

Tags: facebook, query-string

I've created a small facebook application that posts a link to the user's profile. I want the link to reference my application with a certain querystring for me to know what data to present him.

Is it possible? how can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use normal get parameters in the link

Comment: how can I? In order to link to my application I need to give this path:
http://apps.facebook.com/myApplication/

If I try adding something after the last '/' I get an error... What to do?

Comment: you should not get an error

test
http://apps.facebook.com/meinklub/teams/ e.g.
teams is passed as get